# background-clip: border-box behaves like its value were padding-box

Tags: css

I am playing with the `background-clip` property to see the effect of its three values.

Just a few minutes ago, the value `border-box` stopped displaying the image like it should. That is, it was starting the image at the edge of the outer border but now it starts it inside the border but at the end of the `padding-box`.

Please see the code [here on github](https://github.com/Sathyaish/Practice/blob/master/CSS/background.html) and the [JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Sathyaish/1woh1yzf/4/).

In my browser, they all display like so:

[image]

As you can see, the first box that has the value `border-box` for the `background-clip` property does not display the image at the edge of the outer border. It instead behaves exactly like `padding-box`.

Below is also the code for your convenience.

```css
div {
  margin: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.7);
  border-width: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sathyaish/Practice/master/CSS/images/roses-small.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(120, 210, 180, 0.65);
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.default {
  background-clip: border-box;
}

.paddingBox {
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.contentBox {
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="default">background-clip: border-box</div>
<div class="paddingBox">background-clip: padding-box</div>
<div class="contentBox">background-clip: content-box</div>
```

Interestingly, if I comment out the `background-repeat: no-repeat`, all the `background-clip` values behave as they should. Please see the picture below.

```
div {
  .. 
  /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
}
```

[image]

The [W3C CSS 3 Specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-clip) does not state any relation between the `background-clip` and `background-repeat` properties.

IP Note: I got the image [from here](https://unsplash.com/photos/pXmbsF70ulM) and modified it.

Comment: Your image is only 200px wide, yet you apply it to an element that is 300px wide, so there ain’t nothing to clip here to begin with. Add for example `background-size:110%;`, and then see what happens ...

Comment: I am going to try that but my confusion is: shouldn't the value `border-box`, i.e. the default value, make the image start displaying at the coordinate (0, 0) from the outer edge of the border?

Comment: No. The job to specify _that_ goes to the `background-origin` property. Default for that is `padding-box`.

Comment: Interesting. I am trying a few things out. You're probably right. Will report back soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified on [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip):

> The background-clip CSS property specifies if an element's background, whether a color or an image, extends underneath its border.

The keyword here being *extends*, the background in your example is not extending anywhere, because you set `background-repeat: no-repeat`. The confusion here comes from the origin of the background, which is specified by the [`background-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin)-property, which defaults to `padding-box`.

If you set the `background-origin` along with the `background-clip`, it will have the result you're looking for.

```css
div {
  margin: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.7);
  border-width: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sathyaish/Practice/master/CSS/images/roses-small.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(120, 210, 180, 0.65);
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.default {
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-origin: border-box;
}

.paddingBox {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-origin: padding-box;
}

.contentBox {
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-origin: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="default">background-clip: border-box</div>
<div class="paddingBox">background-clip: padding-box</div>
<div class="contentBox">background-clip: content-box</div>
```

Comment: You're right as was @CBroe in the comment section. I tried it out. I must retaliate, thought -- it is all very confusing. The names `background-origin` and `background-clip` are apt for the behaviors they ought to exhibit but what confuses is that `background-clip: content-box` also starts the image from the left edge of the content box.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 it actually doesn't start it there, look closely ;-) It starts the image at the `padding-box` but doesn't show the edges because it's not allowed to extend to the padding-box

Comment: Ah! That's a relief! Thanks much very very. :-)